# C Programm output completely changed due to unrelated, empty printf statement

Tags: c, arrays, printf

I have this C program code here, which determines the highest contiguous value for an array:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int inputs[8];
int calcSum(int i, int j);

int main(void) {
        int i, j, maxSum = 0, tempSum = 0;
        int length = sizeof(inputs)/sizeof(inputs[0]);
        for(i=0;i<length;i++) {
                scanf("%d", &inputs[i]);
        }
        for(i=0;i<length;i++) {
                for(j=i;j<length;j++) {
                        tempSum = calcSum(i,j);
                        if(tempSum > maxSum) {
                                maxSum = tempSum;
                        }
                }
        }
        printf("%d\n", maxSum);
        return 0;
}

int calcSum(int i, int j) {
        int c, sum;
        for(c=i;c<=j;c++) {
                sum+=inputs[c];
        }
        return sum;
}
```

Even though this code looks correct to me, it outputs a wrong result. Sampling adding any sort of `printf("")` (can be empty as well) between `tempSum = ...` and `if(tempSum >...)` will make the code output the correct answer for all test cases. I even rewrote the entire code from scratch and still get the same issue.
For example, the number series: 5 2 -1 -2 -4 3 5 -6 should output 8, which it does once the `printf("")` is added, otherwise it outputs 38...and I have no idea why. Can you please explain, where I went wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How can a name of a program, among other things, affect this result?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36184965/how-can-a-name-of-a-program-among-other-things-affect-this-result#comment60005389_36184965)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this code:

```
int calcSum(int i, int j) {
    int c, sum;
    for(c=i;c<=j;c++) {
            sum+=inputs[c];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

You need to make sure you initialize `sum` to a starting value:

```
int calcSum(int i, int j) {
    int c, sum;
    sum=0;
    for(c=i;c<=j;c++) {
            sum+=inputs[c];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Exactly. Using uninitialized local variable => undefined behavior => adding anything can have unexplainable results.

Comment: Not undefined behavior, just unspecified value. The program will compile and run with no problems (other than the meaningless result).

Comment: Thanks so much! Easy solution to a careless mistake.